# pandas from mix data type convert exponential or scientific numbers to integers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, casting

I have been looking for the solution and tried few suggestions but could not get the answer.
I have a column where in string and long numbers are there in form of exponent, and I need to get the full number out of exponent values for further processing.

pandas exponential scientific numbers to integers.

[Click here for Sample Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YCCSg-KBU93SubPXcPo9s8IEz3ZC1uIn/view?usp=sharing)

IT looks like

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

# tried adding this
pd.options.display.float_format = "{:.0f}".format
df = pd.read_csv('Detail Statement.csv')

# tried converting to int by ignoring other types after commenting display.format  
df['Ref Number'] = df['Ref Number'].astype(int, errors='ignore')

# tried map
df['Ref Number'] = df['Ref Number'].map(int)
```

Comment: `1.0984E+11` be converted to `int` but what should be the result of `HSB345678`?

Comment: Conversion of string is not required

Comment: still not found solution sample is   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YCCSg-KBU93SubPXcPo9s8IEz3ZC1uIn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a custom function and use `.apply`

```
def convert(x):
    try:
        return int(float(x))
    except Exception:
        return x

df['Ref Number'] = df['Ref Number'].apply(convert)
df['Ref Number'].iloc[0], type(df['Ref Number'].iloc[0])
'HSB345678', str

df['Ref Number'].iloc[-1] , type(df['Ref Number'].iloc[-1])
201498000000, int
```

If floats are fine then you can use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors` parameter set to `coerce` then use `.fillna` to fill back the strings that are not convertible.

```
df['Ref Number'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Ref Number'], errors='coerce').fillna(df['Ref Number'])

df['Ref Number'].dtype
dtype('O')

df['Ref Number'].iloc[0], type(df['Ref Number'].iloc[0])
'HSB345678', str

df['Ref Number'].iloc[-1] , type(df['Ref Number'].iloc[-1])
201498000000.0, float
```

Comment: ouput is same as input when i added  df.to_csv('output1.csv')